# Watch Kit: is it possible to vibrate watch programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit

Is it possible to vibrate watch while Watch Extension is running? We can do it on iOS in this way (force iPhone to vibrate):

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

I hope there is something similar on WatchKit.

**Update:** I have added issue to Apple radar and recieved the answer:

> Engineering has determined that your bug report (20019274) is a duplicate of another issue (19025053) and will be closed.

19025053 is still open.

**Update 2:** `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound()` not working on watch simulator with any sound ID. Seems like function is not supported.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can now ask the Watch to vibrate if you target **watchOS 2.0**

To do this all you need to do is call `playHaptic` on a `WKInterfaceDevice` instance with any `WKHapticType`. In the example below it will play the notification haptic.

**Swift 3**

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.notification)
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticTypeNotification];
```

You can further read the
[Apple WKInterfaceDevice Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1628128-play)

Comment: This should be the correct answer now :) Let's wait release.

Comment: Would be nice to also have the objective c up :)

Answer (score 5):

That's a great question, but unfortunately the answer is no. WatchKit doesn't have any APIs available to control haptic feedback. If you would really like to see this feature supported, I'd suggest you file a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) as a feature request.

Comment: I hope this feature will be added or revealed in later versions of WatchKit.

Comment: Agreed. If you feel this answer was sufficient, you should mark it as so. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer in objective-c after watchOS 2

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticTypeNotification];
```

Answer (score -3):

With WatchKit, you have to remember that your code runs on the iPhone and not on the watch. Therefore, AudioServicesPlaySystemSound call from a WatchKit extension would run on the iPhone, not on the watch. It will make the iPhone vibrate.

Comment: No, iPhone will not vibrate as well. I understand that AudioServicesPlaySystemSound not working on Apple Watch. I asked for *something similar*.